# Cordova app downloaded images showing in gallery

Tags: android, image, cordova

My application downloads a set of images and stores them in the internal storage by creating a folder.

The problem is the images are being shown in the gallery. This should not happen, is there a way to programatically hide the images but still be usable by the app?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This is only happening to the android version of the app. In the iOS it is not showing in the Camera Roll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends where you download the images: If you download them on your Pictures folder or inside of a public folder from sdcard/internal memory then MediaScanner scan them so your pictures will be visible in the Gallery app.

To avoid this you can try one of the following solutions:

1. Add a .nomedia file inside your destination folder

    OR
2. Download your pictures in app cache directory by using LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY.

Something like

```
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function(fs) {   
        fs.root.getDirectory("media", {create: true}, function(fileDirectoryEntry) {
           // var destFile = fileDirectory + "/" + filename;
           // downloadPicture(srcUrl, destFile); 
        });
    });
```

The downside of this solution is that when the app is removed, your pictures are deleted as well.

Comment: did you mean "try one of the following solutions", or that's step 1 and step 2?
Actually the downside that you mentioned is not a downside on my part at all, since the purpose of the downloading of images is to prevent the app from getting it from the server.

Comment: Sorry.. I missed the OR